# newrelic_rpm,rails gem showing no route in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

i need to check the performance of my rails application. i installed newrelic_rpm.
In environment.rb , the following added:

```
config.gem "newrelic_rpm"
```

then, in browser i gave:

```
http://localhost:3000/newrelic
```

then, it shows the error message as below:

> **Routing Error No route matches "/newrelic" with {:method=>:get}**

Can you please help me to solve this..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 15):

I'm guessing my issue is related to running thin (and other processes) through foreman in development.  I added the following to get the routing and monitoring working:

`config/environments/development.rb`

```
require 'new_relic/rack/developer_mode'
config.middleware.use NewRelic::Rack::DeveloperMode
ENV['NEWRELIC_ENABLE'] = 'true'
```

Setting `ENV['NEWRELIC_ENABLE'] = 'true'` may monitor stuff when you would rather it didn't (rake tasks etc...)

Comment: Thanks for this. Monitoring wasn't working for me at first with the first 2 links in my config.ru, then I added the last line to my development environment and all is well now

Answer (score 6):

Developer Mode has been removed from `newrelic_rpm` as of early 2017:

https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/commit/ec8e2ee17dd6f5801b9bf1793b8be048d9a9242c

If you still want to use it, you must install an older version of the rubygem, e.g.:

```rb
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '4.0.0.332'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Rails 3.0.5, after upgrading from newrelic_rpm 2.13.4 -> 2.14.0

I followed information from here:
http://support.newrelic.com/discussions/support/5547-cant-access-developer-mode

... I added the following at the top of the file my `$RAILS_ROOT/config.ru` file

```
require 'new_relic/rack_app'
use NewRelic::Rack::DeveloperMode
```

I am expecting this issue to be fixed in a later release of newpreic_rpm

I've also notice a change in the `newrelic.yaml` file format that should be in the `config` directory. You can download this from your newrelic account homepage (account > deploy > ruby) after creating an account (there is a basic free version).

Basically, it looks like:

```
common: &default_settings

  license_key: '[ Your unique license key ]'

  app_name: My Application

  # When "true", the agent collects performance data about your 
  # application and reports this data to the NewRelic RPM service at 
  # newrelic.com. This global switch is normally overridden for each 
  # environment below. (formerly called 'enabled')
  monitor_mode: true

  # Developer mode should be off in every environment but
  # development as it has very high overhead in memory.
  developer_mode: false

  # The newrelic agent generates its own log file to keep its logging
  # information separate from that of your application.  Specify its
  # log level here.
  log_level: info

  # The newrelic agent communicates with the RPM service via http by
  # default.  If you want to communicate via https to increase
  # security, then turn on SSL by setting this value to true.  Note,
  # this will result in increased CPU overhead to perform the
  # encryption involved in SSL communication, but this work is done
  # asynchronously to the threads that process your application code,
  # so it should not impact response times.
  ssl: false

  # EXPERIMENTAL: enable verification of the SSL certificate sent by
  # the server. This setting has no effect unless SSL is enabled
  # above. This may block your application. Only enable it if the data
  # you send us needs end-to-end verified certificates.
  #
  # This means we cannot cache the DNS lookup, so each request to the
  # RPM service will perform a lookup. It also means that we cannot
  # use a non-blocking lookup, so in a worst case, if you have DNS
  # problems, your app may block indefinitely.
  # verify_certificate: true

  # Set your application's Apdex threshold value with the 'apdex_t'
  # setting, in seconds. The apdex_t value determines the buckets used
  # to compute your overall Apdex score. 
  # Requests that take less than apdex_t seconds to process will be
  # classified as Satisfying transactions; more than apdex_t seconds
  # as Tolerating transactions; and more than four times the apdex_t
  # value as Frustrating transactions. 
  # For more about the Apdex standard, see
  # http://support.newrelic.com/faqs/general/apdex

  apdex_t: 0.5

  # Proxy settings for connecting to the RPM server.
  #
  # If a proxy is used, the host setting is required.  Other settings
  # are optional.  Default port is 8080.
  #
  # proxy_host: hostname
  # proxy_port: 8080
  # proxy_user:
  # proxy_pass:


  # Tells transaction tracer and error collector (when enabled)
  # whether or not to capture HTTP params.  When true, frameworks can
  # exclude HTTP parameters from being captured.
  # Rails: the RoR filter_parameter_logging excludes parameters
  # Java: create a config setting called "ignored_params" and set it to
  #     a comma separated list of HTTP parameter names.
  #     ex: ignored_params: credit_card, ssn, password 
  capture_params: false


  # Transaction tracer captures deep information about slow
  # transactions and sends this to the RPM service once a
  # minute. Included in the transaction is the exact call sequence of
  # the transactions including any SQL statements issued.
  transaction_tracer:

    # Transaction tracer is enabled by default. Set this to false to
    # turn it off. This feature is only available at the Silver and
    # above product levels.
    enabled: true

    # Threshold in seconds for when to collect a transaction
    # trace. When the response time of a controller action exceeds
    # this threshold, a transaction trace will be recorded and sent to
    # RPM. Valid values are any float value, or (default) "apdex_f",
    # which will use the threshold for an dissatisfying Apdex
    # controller action - four times the Apdex T value.
    transaction_threshold: apdex_f

    # When transaction tracer is on, SQL statements can optionally be
    # recorded. The recorder has three modes, "off" which sends no
    # SQL, "raw" which sends the SQL statement in its original form,
    # and "obfuscated", which strips out numeric and string literals
    record_sql: obfuscated

    # Threshold in seconds for when to collect stack trace for a SQL
    # call. In other words, when SQL statements exceed this threshold,
    # then capture and send to RPM the current stack trace. This is
    # helpful for pinpointing where long SQL calls originate from
    stack_trace_threshold: 0.500

    # Determines whether the agent will capture query plans for slow
    # SQL queries.  Only supported in mysql and postgres.  Should be
    # set to false when using other adapters.
    # explain_enabled: true

    # Threshold for query execution time below which query plans will not 
    # not be captured.  Relevant only when `explain_enabled` is true.
    # explain_threshold: 0.5

  # Error collector captures information about uncaught exceptions and
  # sends them to RPM for viewing
  error_collector:

    # Error collector is enabled by default. Set this to false to turn
    # it off. This feature is only available at the Silver and above
    # product levels
    enabled: true

    # Rails Only - tells error collector whether or not to capture a 
    # source snippet around the place of the error when errors are View 
    # related.
    capture_source: true    

    # To stop specific errors from reporting to RPM, set this property
    # to comma separated values.  Default is to ignore routing errors
    # which are how 404's get triggered.
    #
    ignore_errors: ActionController::RoutingError

  # (Advanced) Uncomment this to ensure the cpu and memory samplers
  # won't run.  Useful when you are using the agent to monitor an
  # external resource
  # disable_samplers: true

  # If you aren't interested in visibility in these areas, you can
  # disable the instrumentation to reduce overhead.
  #
  # disable_view_instrumentation: true
  # disable_activerecord_instrumentation: true
  # disable_memcache_instrumentation: true
  # disable_dj: true

  # Certain types of instrumentation such as GC stats will not work if 
  # you are running multi-threaded.  Please let us know.
  # multi_threaded = false

# Application Environments
# ------------------------------------------
# Environment specific settings are in this section.
# For Rails applications, RAILS_ENV is used to determine the environment
# For Java applications, pass -Dnewrelic.environment <environment> to set
# the environment

# NOTE if your application has other named environments, you should
# provide newrelic configuration settings for these environments here.

development:
  <<: *default_settings
  # Turn off communication to RPM service in development mode (also 
  # 'enabled').
  # NOTE: for initial evaluation purposes, you may want to temporarily 
  # turn the agent on in development mode.
  monitor_mode: false

  # Rails Only - when running in Developer Mode, the New Relic Agent will 
  # present performance information on the last 100 transactions you have
  # executed since starting the mongrel.
  # NOTE: There is substantial overhead when running in developer mode.
  # Do not use for production or load testing.  
  developer_mode: true

  # Enable textmate links
  # textmate: true

test:
  <<: *default_settings
  # It almost never makes sense to turn on the agent when running
  # unit, functional or integration tests or the like.
  monitor_mode: false

# Turn on the agent in production for 24x7 monitoring.  NewRelic
# testing shows an average performance impact of < 5 ms per
# transaction, you you can leave this on all the time without
# incurring any user-visible performance degradation.
production:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true

# Many applications have a staging environment which behaves
# identically to production.  Support for that environment is provided
# here.  By default, the staging environment has the agent turned on.
staging:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
  app_name: My Application (Staging)
```

Comment: fixed the issue for me, though the dev mode still never sees any transactions.  Does this count for putting it in the "middleware stack"?

Comment: On rails 3.1.3 you have to add the following lines to your config.ru (section "Developer Mode in Rack Applications" on http://newrelic.github.com/rpm/):

require 'new_relic/rack/developer_mode'
use NewRelic::Rack::DeveloperMode